# On click event of image button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem that when I click on the image button instead of redirect me to the corresponding page, it will just redirect back to the same page.

This is the code in asp;

```
  <asp:ImageButton ID="header1" src="Resources/Icons/Header1.jpg" runat="server" />
```

And this is in my page load in the code behind;

```
  header1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "~/ChildSelection.aspx");
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Image button should have an onclick event.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="header1" ImageUrl="Resources/Icons/Header1.jpg" runat="server" OnClick="header1_Click" />

protected void header1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/ChildSelection.aspx");
}
```

Comment: The OP needs help with how he has already chosen to handle the event by adding the attribute.

Comment: @SkonJeet This event runs at `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve it by replacing it by

```
header1.Attributes.Add("PostBackUrl", "~/ChildSelection.aspx");
```

Onclick is an event. You might also consider using a hyperlink with ImageSrc property instead of an ImageButton.

[Edit]

If you are just trying to redirect a better approach could be

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="header1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Resources/Icons/Header1.jpg">Click Here</asp:HyperLink>
```

And in code behind

```
header1.NavigateUrl = "~/ChildSelection.aspx";
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` event executes javascript if I'm not mistaking. `OnClick` refers to a server-side event. Try setting the window's location to redirect to the corresponding page.

```
 header1.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
   string.Format("window.location = '{0}'", ResolveClientUrl("~/ChildSelection.aspx")));
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="header1" src="Resources/Icons/Header1.jpg" runat="server" PostBackURL="~/ChildSelection.aspx"/>
```